# Idea with PHP (not only) error handling & IDE jump-to-error-line

Tags: ide, error-handling

I have some idea with error handling in PHP - way to immediately get to place in code where error occurred.

I have written error handler to catch PHP errors, which loads file, that caused an error and displays +/- few lines of code from that file. It also mark line where error occurred and print stack trace, like this:

http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/3754/errh.png

Now, I have an idea, to provide some link (a href=) like other than http protocols (torrent:// or sth), like "netbeans://C:/some/file.php@110" which will put me back into NetBeans editor, open file where error occurred and put cursor in line, which caused a error.

Any ideas how to achieve that goal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is register a custom url protocol. The techniques depend on the underlying operating system. [here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2006/10/19/register-a-custom-url-protocol-handler.aspx) is an example for windows. By opening NetBeans with a system call and the `--open [filename]` argument, you can open the file in question. However, that way you won't be able to go to a specific line.

In order to do so, you need to use the [NetBeans API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/). If needed, you can use [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com) to access Java functionality from .NET languages (which you'd need for windows).

All in all, it won't be easy and not cross-platform. A much easier way to go is to use [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/) on the server side and implement the library in the NetBeans editor, which will allow a lot more functionality than what you currently try to accomplish (stack traces, Jumping in Code, Stepping, variable views, ... - just to name a few). There seems to be a [started proposal](http://wiki.netbeans.org/PHPDebugging) on this for the NetBeans editor.

If you do not care to switch the editor, you can check out Eclipse PHP Development Tools ([Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)), which has the debugger already implemented. Check out [this article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2930) on the setup instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use xDebug with Netbean's xdebug integration which already jumps to the errors.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans IDE already has this option

Please open your project in NetBeans IDE.

main menu -> options -> editor -> hints -> select language php & select all check-boxes.

then refresh project show highlighting errors or undefined variables warnings.

[image]

if more with NetBeans IDE
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/editorguide.html